# How to start activity from BroadcastReceiver onReceive method?

Tags: android, service, popup, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog

I need a dialog box or a custom dialog to appear when the BroadcastReceiver onReceive() is called!!

Anybody knows it..please help me
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `startActivity()` on the `Context` supplied to `onReceive()`, including `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in the flags of the `Intent` you pass to `startActivity()`.

Note that starting an activity without the user initiating it may be considered poor form by the user.